# I'm trying to Create a statistics function without using any libraries

Tags: python-3.x

ps: please don't mind my code, this programmer is very new to coding :)
I'm trying to create a function that returns a dictionary of statistical outputs without importing any library. (*I haven't gotten there yet in my code below*), i'm just testing the median part of the code but I am getting an error "**TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable**".
I know the median in my code is not the actual formula to get the median but I'm wondering why i'm getting the error. any help will be appreciated.

```
### START FUNCTION
def dictionary_of_metrics(items):
    # your code here
    sumsd = 0
    values = []
    n = len(items)
    dic = ['mean', 'median', 'var', 'std', 'min', 'max']
    mean = float(sum(items)/n)
    values.append(mean)
    med_list = items.sort
    if n % 2 == 0:
        median = med_list[n] + med_list[n]
    else:
        median = float(med_list[(len(med_list) // 2)])
    for item in items:
        sumsd = float(sumsd + ((item - mean)**2))
    sd = float(sumsd/n)
    var = float(sd**2)
    values.append(sd)
    values.append(var)
    minimum = float(min(items))
    values.append(minimum)
    maximum = float(max(items))
    values.append(maximum)

    return median

print(dictionary_of_metrics([1,2,3,4,5,6]))
```

the code for the median actually looks like this but still, I get an error:

```
if len(items) % 2 == 0:
        median = float((med_list[len((items/2) - 1)] + med_list[len(items/2)])/2)
    else:
        median = float(med_list[(len(med_list) // 2)])
```

Comment: `items.sort()`.

Answer (score 0):

.sort is a function.
You should call it.

```
med_list = items.sort()
```

Comment: Ref: https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_list_sort.asp

Comment: thanks for your comment, but the error persists

Comment: Sort returns None.